# class="fa fa-facebook share function not working

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, woocommerce

Currently on my website when user click the share icon to share a product on their own facebook profile, nothing happens.

When users click on the share icon for Twitter, they are able to share a prewritten tweet about the product.

I'm not sure why the facebook icon is not working correctly. I'm using a very old version of the wordpress theme Bridge.

Thank you,

this is on http://www.frankmurphyfashions.com/product/reversible-tote-charges-phone/ but is happening for all our products.

Comment: Add the relevant code to the question instead of a link to your website.

Comment: When you were presented with the Stack Overflow Tour a few minutes ago, we would have preferred that you pay attention to its contents. That would have taught you how to ask a question that would not only get you the help you seek, but also help _us_ and future visitors. This is not a personal helpdesk. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have line-breaks in your link (inside the `window.open('`

This **will not** work:

```html
<a title="Share on Facebook" href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=Reversible Tote that Charges your Phone&amp;p[summary]=These totes are a 4-in-1 gift item!  The tote is reversible so it can be worn two different ways.  On the inside, is a wristlet that can be removed and worn on it\'s own.  Inside of that is a battery pack that can be removed and used in ALL your purses!  It\'s a strong battery pack that will recharge your phone a couple times before it needs to be charged.  To charge the battery pack, it\'s a USB device so it\'s very simple!  The pack comes with adapters for both the standard android and iphone plug ins, so if you have the android phone and the current ipad, it will actually work for both!

&nbsp;

Fabric Content: Vegan Leather&amp;p[url]=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.frankmurphyfashions.com%2Fproduct%2Freversible-tote-charges-phone%2F&amp;&p[images][0]=http://www.frankmurphyfashions.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/handbag-butler-reversible-tote-black-tan-5.jpg', 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=620,height=280');">Click to share</a>
```

And this **will work**:

```html
<a title="Share on Facebook" href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=Reversible Tote that Charges your Phone&amp;p[summary]=These totes are a 4-in-1 gift item!  The tote is reversible so it can be worn two different ways.  On the inside, is a wristlet that can be removed and worn on it\'s own.  Inside of that is a battery pack that can be removed and used in ALL your purses!  It\'s a strong battery pack that will recharge your phone a couple times before it needs to be charged.  To charge the battery pack, it\'s a USB device so it\'s very simple!  The pack comes with adapters for both the standard android and iphone plug ins, so if you have the android phone and the current ipad, it will actually work for both!Fabric Content: Vegan Leather&amp;p[url]=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.frankmurphyfashions.com%2Fproduct%2Freversible-tote-charges-phone%2F&amp;&p[images][0]=http://www.frankmurphyfashions.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/handbag-butler-reversible-tote-black-tan-5.jpg', 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=620,height=280');">Click to share</a>
```

> Note that specifically the snippet will not work here in stackoverflow because it is blocked.

You should fix it in the source of the page.

Comment: I believe the lines are automatically generated. He will have to change the back-end so it doesn't pass it with lines.

Comment: You are probably right about it.